# JSON Wrapper Class not Deserializtion

Tags: apex, trigger, json, wrapper-class

I have some JSON coming in that's like this (data removed for privacy reasons.

`{"user":{"id":"","email":"","first_name":"","last_name":""}, "STUFF I DONT WANT HERE"}`

I wrote an inner wrapper class for it like this:

```
    public with sharing class WrapperUserJson {
        public String id;
        public String email;
        public String first_name;
        public String last_name;
    }
```

In a method I am doing something like
`WrapperUserJson data = (WrapperUserJson)JSON.deserialize(st, WrapperUserJson.class);`

But it always returns null. I know for a fact that the JSON is being passed to it so I don't get it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the top-level attribute `user`. You need a second wrapper class:

```
public class WrapperResponseJson {
    WrapperUserJson user;
}
public class WrapperUserJson {
    public String id;
    public String email;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
}
```

Which you then feed into the deserialize method:

```
WrapperResponseJson data = (WrapperResponseJson)JSON.deserialize(st, WrapperResponseJson.class);
```

You can automatically generate code from JSON using [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/), a great tool for quickly creating Apex from a given JSON source.